# How to save whole function outputs to a text file? C++

Tags: c++, function, ofstream, file-writing

so I have created a Dice Tally Generator which is in of itself a difficult task for me. And there's an option in my program to display and save the last Tally output into a text file. How do I save the output of whole functions to a text file? The save option is located under "case 5" inside the switch. And I must save the output in "case 4". Thanks in Advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
using namespace std;

int runMenu;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int menuInput;
    bool menu = true;
    ifstream inFile;
    string ABOUT;
    const unsigned int sizeArray = 12;
    const unsigned int maxDice = 6;
    const unsigned int throwableDice = 2;
    const unsigned int maxRoll = 100;
    const unsigned int possibleSum = 11;
    int numArray[sizeArray];
    int diceRoll;
    int rolls;
    int tallyResult[possibleSum];
    int result[maxRoll][throwableDice];
    int sum[maxRoll];
    int possibleResult;
    ofstream save; 
    int y = true;
    int n = false;

    // Menu Interface
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout << "   The Tally Ho Probability Generator (MCD4720_Assignment 1)\n";
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout << " [1] End Testing the Program\n";
    cout << " [2] Display About Information\n";
    cout << " [3] Read and store data from files\n";
    cout << " [4] Generate a Dice Tally Table\n";
    cout << " [5] Save Tally Statistics to a file\n";
    cout << " [6] Load Tally Statistics from a file\n";
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout << "Which Option would you like (1-6)\n";
    cin >> runMenu;

    // Menu Input Function
    while (menu == 1) {
        switch (runMenu)
        {
        case 1:
        {//Program Shutdown
            exit(0);
        }

        case 2:
        {//Display Text
            inFile.open("C:\\Users\\William\\Documents\\MCD Assignment 4720 1\\TallyAbout.txt");
            while (getline(inFile, ABOUT)) {
                cout << ABOUT << endl;
            }
            inFile.close();
            cout << " Press any key to continue \n";
            system("pause");
        }
        case 3:
        {
        }
        case 4:
        {//Dice Tally Generator
            diceRoll = 0;
            while (!(diceRoll <= 2 && diceRoll > 0)) {
                cout << "How many dice to roll (1-2): ";
                cin >> diceRoll;
            }
            cout << endl;
            rolls = 0;

            while (!(rolls <= 10 && rolls > 0)) {
                cout << "How many rolls required (1-10): ";
                cin >> rolls;
            }
            rolls = rolls * 10;
            cout << endl;

            cout << "You Rolled " << diceRoll << " dice " << rolls << " times.\n";
            cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
            // Initialize tally
            for (int i = 0;i < possibleSum;i++) {
                tallyResult[i] = 0;
            }
            // Sum store the total number for each rolls
            for (int i = 0;i < maxRoll;i++) {
                sum[i] = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rolls; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < diceRoll; j++) {
                    result[i][j] = rand() % maxDice + 1;
                    sum[i] += result[i][j];
                }
                tallyResult[(sum[i] - diceRoll)]++;  
            }
            possibleResult = (maxDice - 1) * diceRoll + 1;
            for (int i = 0;i < possibleResult;i++) {
                if ( i + diceRoll < 10)
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << (i + diceRoll) << ": ";
                for (int j = 0;j < tallyResult[i];j++) {
                    cout << "*";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        case 5:
            //Saving Last Displayed Tally
        {
            save.open("C:\\Users\\William\\Documents\\MCD Assignment 4720 1\\savedTallyData.txt");
            save;
            save.close();


        }
        case 6:
        {}
        default: {
            cout << " Please Choose Another Option \n";
            cin >> runMenu;
            break;
        }

               cin.ignore();
               cin.get();
               return 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reproduce the loop where you print the results in case 4, but changing `cout` to `save`.

Comment: You don't need this amount of code to create a [mcve]. You could probably demonstrate what you are trying to do with ~10 lines of code. Note, `bool` is a built-in type in C++, don't `#include <stdbool.h>`. It's a C header and it's useless in C++. Also, `#include <ctime>` not the C header `time.h`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Apologies... I've only recently started coding and I've been in the site for 3 days. I'm a big noob

Comment: Thanks!! @JohnnyMopp I'll try this

Comment: @TheRandomMovieman No apologies needed. I'm just trying to help you to present the problem in a way that will make more people take a look at it. Read [mcve] to get more hints.

Comment: That absolute file path will break as soon as you try to run the code on a different machine. Like say the machine you submit your homework to. If the requirement is to just save the file in the same place as the executable, you can just write the file name. And instead of repeating code, note that you could have a function to write data, and you pass it the stream you want to do the writing. Probably best to stick with the repetition for now.

Comment: I've been poking around your code. It's weird. Could you please add your actual problem statement to the question?